# Can't get this basic loop to function

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

If someone can please help me understand why this first piece of code works and the other doesn't:

```
var i = 1;
while (i <= 20){
    if (i & 15 === 0) {
        console.log("JuliaJames");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Julia");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("James");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
    i++;   
}
```

and this doesn't work:

```
var i = 1;
while (i <= 20){
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i & 5 === 0) {
        console.log("JuliaJames");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Julia");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("James");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
    i++;   
}
```

Comment: Probably, both work, but with different output. What you expect to get? Did you try to understand what is going on in code (the most interesting part for you — the conditions of both first `if`)

Comment: `1 & 5` looks like you meant to mod that.

Comment: I think you meant to use `i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0` in the second example

Comment: `&` and `%` perform different operations.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the expressions i % 3 and i & 5 in parentheses and it will work as expected.

```
var i = 1;
while (i <= 20){
    if ((i % 3) === 0 && (i & 5) === 0) {
        console.log("JuliaJames");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Julia");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("James");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
    i++;   
}
```